# How to implement forms in a terminal?

Tags: node.js, bash, command-line-interface, zsh

I write alot of bash/zsh/nodejs scripts, and would like to allow an option to specify some options interactively in a terminal based form.

So for example, say I run a program like so:

```
foo -name=test -dir=/tmp -output=tmp/it.txt
```

I'd like to be able to display a form that had those options as default values, and possibly had other values in lists that I could choose.

Is there some way to do this that already exists?

I think it'd be great if I could specify those options in some json, and then pass them to a program which launched my program after,

for example, with json like so in a file named `args.json`

```
{
    "program": "foo",
    "args": {
        "name": "test",
        "dir": "/tmp",
        "output": "tmp/it.txt"
    }
}
```

I could run

```
form_runner args.json
```

and it'd display a form that let me interactively fill in the form in a terminal, and by hitting `enter`, it'd run the program.

Comment: have you tried blessed ? https://github.com/chjj/blessed

Comment: Why not write one? It wouldn't take too long I guess.

Comment: Have you looked at [`dialog`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog)?

Comment: @ymonad - Blessed looks like the best option so far... thanks a ton! You should add that as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in pure nodejs, using https://github.com/chjj/blessed would be easy.

If you want to do it with bash, [dialog](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) or [zenity](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/) (requires X) would be the option.

Here's the sample program which uses blessed. you can run it with `npm install blessed` and `node the_script.js args.json` .

```
var blessed = require('blessed'), fs = require('fs'), child_process = require('child_process');

const TITLE_PROG="program:";

fs.readFile(process.argv[2], function(err,data){
  var js = JSON.parse(data)
  var screen = blessed.screen({
    autoPadding: true,
    smartCSR: true
  });
  var form = blessed.form({
    parent: screen,
    width: 60,
    height: 4,
    keys: true
  });
  blessed.text({
    parent: form,
    fg: 'cyan',
    content: TITLE_PROG
  })
  var prog = blessed.textbox({
    parent: form,
    name:'program',
    inputOnFocus: true,
    value: js['program'],
    left: TITLE_PROG.length + 1
  })
  var texts = Object.keys(js['args']).forEach(function(key,index){
    blessed.text({
      parent: form,
      top: index + 1,
      content: key + ':',
      fg:'green'
    })
    blessed.textbox({
      parent: form,
      inputOnFocus: true,
      name: key,
      value: js['args'][key],
      top: index + 1,
      left: key.length + 2
    })
  })

  form.on('submit', function(data){
    screen.leave();
    var prog = data['program'] 
    delete data['program']
    var cmd = prog + ' ' + Object.keys(data).map(function(key){return '-' + key + ' "' + data[key] + '"'}).join(' ')
    child_process.exec(cmd,function(error,stdout,stderr){
      screen.leave();
      console.log('stdout: ' + stdout)
      console.log('stderr: ' + stderr)
      if(error !== null){
        console.log('error: ' + error)
        process.exit(error.code);
      }
      process.exit(0);
    })
  })
  screen.key(['enter'], function(){
    form.submit();
  });

  screen.key(['escape','C-c'], function(){
    screen.leave();
    process.exit(0);
  });

  prog.focus()

  screen.render();

})
```

Comment: that's great! thanks a ton for the effort, as this rocks!